# перестал работать push после переноса на https

Tags: git, nginx, https, gitlab

Имеется сервер gitlab+gitlab_ci

```
GitLab information
Version:    7.14.3
Revision:   d321305
```

Первоначально был настроен на http.
После реконфигурации nginx на https (прошу заметить что изменения настроек касались именно web-сервера) пуш в любой репозиторий стал выдавать ошибку

```
GitLab: API is not accessible
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

$ git remote -v
  origin    git@gitlab.domain.com:[MEMBER]/[REPO].git (fetch)
  origin    git@gitlab.domain.com:[MEMBER]/[REPO].git (push)
```

Где тут связь между ssh и https?
Почему перестали пуши делаться?
Просмотрел логи nginx и gitlab - не нашел ничего что могло бы указывать на проблему.
Репозиторий (проект) в браузере открывается. Конфиг nginx для gitlab брался из репозитория гитлаба.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не внимательно прочитал документацию:

1.Нужно было изменить конфиг gitlab.yml (добавить https и порт)

2. изменить конфиг gitlab-shell/config.yml (добавить https)
3. ребутнуть сервис

После этого все стало работать.

Comment: Интересно, что делать сейчас в условиях санкций?)